# Express the inverse of $A^T$ in terms of $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A ∈ M$ $n×n(R)$ be an invertible matrix. Prove that $A^T$
is also invertible,
and express the inverse of $A^T$
in terms of $A^{-1}$.

We've already proven the first part, its just the second part that we need a hand with. 
Thanks.

Comment: How do transposition and multiplication interact?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A \cdot A^{-1} = \rm{id} = A^{-1} \cdot A$.

> What happens if you transpose everything?

Answer (score 1):

$A^T(A^{-1})^T=(A^{-1}A)^T= I$         (By properties of matrix transpose)
which means $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$    (By definition of matrix inverse)

Answer (score 1):

This follows up on Daniel Fischer's comment:

Suppose you know that
$$
\begin{align}
& (AB)^T (\text{with $A$ on the left and $B$ on the right}) \\[6pt]
={} & B^T A^T (\text{with $B$ on the left and $A$ on the right}).
\end{align}
$$

Now suppose that $A$ and $B$ are each other's inverses.  Then
$$
I = I^T = (AB)^T = B^T A^T.
$$
$$
I = I^T = (BA)^T = A^T B^T.
$$

That tells you what the inverse of $A^T$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\det A=\det A^t\\{}\\\bullet&\;\;
\left(A^t\right)^{-1}=\left(A^{-1}\right)^t\end{align*}$$